# Populate a text box using ajax

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I'm trying to write an AJAX script, but I can not figure it out.

When a name is entered, a query must be run that searches for the person's ID.

**JQUERY/HTML**

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $("searchName").change(function(){
   var name = $("searchName").val();
   $.post("searchid.php", {
    naam: name
   }, function(data, status) {
    $("#test").html(data);
    });
   });
  });
</script>
```

```html
<table>
<div class="auto-widget">
 <tr>
     <td><lable>Naam</lable></td>
     <td><input name="serarchName" class="tagert" type="text" id="searchName"/></td>
    <tr>
    <tr>
     <td><lable>id</lable></td>
     <td><input type="text" id="tmnlId"/></td>
    <tr> 
</div>
</table>

<p id="test"></p>
```

**PHP**

```
 //set $server, $user, $password and $database_name, then establish the connection:
    $conn = new mysqli($dbHost, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName);
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        exit("FALSE");
    }

    $naam = $_POST["naam"];
    $query=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM Medewerkers WHERE naam ='".$naam."'");
    $row=mysqli_fetch_array($query);
    echo $row['id'];

    ?>
    enter code here
```

Comment: So what exactly is your issue?

Comment: When something is filled in, nothing happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your jQuery selector is probably the cause of your problem. Its missing `#`.

Change jquery to:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#searchName").change(function(){
        var name = $("#searchName").val();
        $.post("searchid.php", {
            naam: name
        }, function(data, status) {
            $("#test").html(data);
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```